# Passing an array as part of an object to an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Until now, I've been successfully passing an array of strings to my controller via AJAX using JSON.stringify.

However, now I need to move that array into another object in order to pass more data to the AJAX call.

The following (and many other attempts) result in the jobRequest.Tests having no members when passed to the controller:

```
    function executeTests(testsToRun) {
        if (testsToRun.length > 0) {
            var jobRequest = new Object;
            jobRequest.SampleTitle = '@ViewBag.SampleTitle';
            jobRequest.SampleLanguage = '@ViewBag.SampleLanguage';
            jobRequest.Mode = '@ViewBag.SampleMode';
            jobRequest.Tests = JSON.stringify(testsToRun);
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ProcessJob", "ProcessJob")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'jobRequest': jobRequest }),
                success: function (jobId) {
                    window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "ProcessJob")' + '?id=' + jobId;
                }
            });
        }
    }

public class JobRequest
{
    public string SampleTitle { get; set; }
    public string SampleLanguage { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tests = new List<string>();
}

public JsonResult ProcessJob(JobRequest jobRequest)
{
    ...
```

Comment: Use `jobRequest.Tests = testsToRun;` instead of `jobRequest.Tests = JSON.stringify(testsToRun);`

Comment: That was one of my earlier attempts, but yields an empty list for jobRequest.Tests in the controller's method.

Comment: I'm curious how this is supposed to work, afaik `data` is always supposed to be either 1) a query string or 2)an object of key=>value pairs, and you are passing it neither (just a JSON string). It looks like your serverside language is java, I'm not sure how that handles that situation. Can you post the code that *did* work "until now"?

Comment: @chili: the request body (i.e. `data`) can be of any format as long as the server can handle it. The content type of the request body is specified with the `contentType` option. So, since that says that the content type is JSON, sending anything else than JSON would be incorrect. By default jQuery sends the data encoded as a query string, but it's perfectly ok to change this.

Comment: ooh neat. @FelixKling I think I was getting mixed up with `$.post()`. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the class **JobRequest** like this:

```
public class JobRequest
{
    public string SampleTitle { get; set; }
    public string SampleLanguage { get; set; }
    public string Mode { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tests { get; set; }
}
```

and remove the **JSON.stringify** in the array:

```
jobRequest.Tests = testsToRun;
```